# replace value within column if id column matches a different table

Tags: r

If I have:

```
id1 <- c(123,456,789)
val <- c(1,0,1)
df1 <- data.frame(id1,val)

id2 <- c(123,456)
df2 <- data.frame(id2)
```

I want change df1$val to "match" if df1$id1 = df2$id2.

I.e

```
id1    val
___    ___
123  match
456  match
789  1
```

I know I can use `match(df1$id1,df2$id2)` to get the matches but can't work out how to do the replacement.

thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? What would the outcome be? `df1$val <-
 match(df1$id1,df2$id2)`

Comment: Hi sotos have updated

Comment: Maybe use `%in%`? i.e. `df1$id1 %in% df2$id2`